# How to convert a signed decimal into a HEX 24-bits twos-complement signed number

Tags: c#, vb.net

I need  help to send a signed decimal value in an UDP stream following a specific protocol structure. Sending the UDP stream is piece of cake but converting my signed decimal number into a HEX 24-bits twos-component signed number is another story as I don't understand how to do that.

Here is the instructions from that protocol on what I have to send:

> The value is expressed in degrees as a 24-bit twos-complement signed
>   number, where the most-significant bit (bit 23) is the sign bit, the
>   next 8 bits (bits 22 to 15) are the integer part and the remaining
>   bits (bits 14 to 0) are the fractional part; alternatively, this may
>   be thought of as a signed integer value in units of 1/ 32768 degree.
>   The range of values is from -180.0 degrees (A60000 hex) to +180.0
>   degrees (5A0000 hex).

I know I'm asking a lot if if some one can post a piece of working code in VB or C# it would be really appreciated.

Comment: Hi Plutonix, may I ask you why you edited my question ?

Comment: There is no question in your post.

Comment: Hahaha... ok... I see... So let's be clear, here is my question : Can you give me a piece of code that will convert a signed decimal number to a 24-bits twos-component signed number as described in my first post (the yellow part of it) ?

Comment: @MadeByVince 1) always put your question in the post itself, not in the comments, 2) StackOverflow is here to help you with your existing programming issues, not to write code for you.

Comment: @MadeByVince Plutonix's edits removed extra info that isn't needed in your post.

Comment: To get you started, use [`Decimal.GetBits()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.getbits(v=vs.110).aspx). You can pluck out what you need and manipulate as needed.

Comment: Hi  MadeByVince  is this freeD protocol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to send three bytes down the stream, though it's not clear in what order. You also have to be sure it's in the right range. Assuming MSB first:

```
WriteBytes(decimal value, Stream stream)
{
    Int32 intValue = (int)(value * 32768);
    byte byte1 = (byte)(intValue & 255);
    intValue >>=8;
    byte byte2 = (byte)(intValue & 255);
    intValue >>=8;
    byte byte3 = (byte)(intValue & 255);
    stream.Write(byte3);
    stream.Write(byte2);
    stream.Write(byte1);
}
```

Comment: Any comments? Or just downvotes?

Comment: Thanks a lot... I'll try this :)

Comment: I believe it will work for negative numbers but not absolutely sure.

Comment: Just tried it and it is working with negative perfectly but not with decimal and you used Int32.... I'm working on this :)

Comment: What do you mean? It does work with decimal. `value` is a decimal. And it should work with a double too.

Comment: oops... you're right sorry.... I made a mistake when I modified your code to work on a form (textbox for getting the value and textbox to show the converted result)...  My bad...  Thank you very much for your precious help

Comment: Glad I could help.. Man this place is becoming hostile.. As soon as I posted my answer it showed up with a -1.

Comment: Oh yeah, I quickly noticed :)  This is a really common problem with programming places... People seems to think that giving the answer is not the right method... OK, I can understand, but did the guy who teached you how to drive car just gave you the car manual ? If you ask someone help to move a heavy box do he simply tell you to go to gym to get stronger so you'll be able to take it just by yourself ? Sure if you teach someone how to fish we will get food for his life but sometimes simple and humble help is welcome.. maybe that guy have no arm and will never be able to fish on its own... :)